# TikZ: automatic line breaking in equal distances

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an elegant way to break an arc into n equal pieces?  I am discussing the surface area of sphere in my document, `SA = 2\pi r l`.  Therefore, I want to start from an arc with n (3, 4, or 5) line segment approximations and then I will look at taking the limit of sum as n goes to infinity.

I can't think of a way to break out n equal spaced lines on my arc where n is the the number I decide to go with.  All I have at the moment is the arc.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\draw (O) arc[radius = 2, start angle = 15, end angle = 75];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a macro that generates `n` segments to approximate an arc with the actual arc shown in gray:

[image]

### Notes:

- The example of `n=3` is to show that you can start at angles other than zero.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

% Ensure we are not overriding any existing macro
\newcommand*{\DeltaAngle}{}
\newcommand*{\CurrentStartAngle}{}
\newcommand*{\CurrentEndAngle}{}
\newcommand*{\SegmentedArc}[5][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = number of segments
    % #3 = arc start angle
    % #4 = arc end angle
    % #5 = radius
    \draw [thin, gray] (#3:#5) arc [radius = #5, start angle = #3, end angle = #4];
    %
    \node [below, #1] at (#3:#5) {$n=#2$};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaAngle}{(#4-#3)/#2}%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\CurrentStartAngle}{#3+(\x-1)*\DeltaAngle}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\CurrentEndAngle}{\CurrentStartAngle+\DeltaAngle}%
        \typeout{\string\CurrentStartAngle=\CurrentStartAngle, \string\CurrentEndAngle=\CurrentEndAngle}%
        \draw [#1] (\CurrentStartAngle:#5cm) -- (\CurrentEndAngle:#5cm);
    }%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    
    \SegmentedArc[thin, blue]{2}{0}{75}{2}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1.0cm]
        \SegmentedArc[thin, red]{3}{15}{75}{2}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.0cm]
        \SegmentedArc[thin, brown]{4}{0}{75}{2}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dustin: See updated code.  Needed an adjustment to how the actual arc was drawn for non-zero start angle.

Comment: This code appears to not work any more.  It works but the lines dont overlay any more.

Comment: @dustin: I still get the same results from the MWE above. What has changed since this was posted that it no longer works?  You should post a follow-up question as I suspect something else is going on. Perhaps use `\listiles` just _before_ `\begin{document}` and include the versions of the packages that are used.